# restricting the width of the submenubar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to restrict the width of the submenu items "Certification" and "Training", Currently it is occupying the whole window size.

Here is the code

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div >
                    @*  @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })*@<img src="~/Images/InfosysLogo.png" style="height:70px;width:200px" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("DashBoard", "ExecutiveDashboard", "Charts")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Engagement Metrics", "EngagementMatrix", "Charts")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Quality Metrics", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("People Aspects", "Contact", "Home")

                    <ul>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Certifications", "Index", "Certification",null, new { @class = "my-class" })</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Trainings", "Index", "Training", null,new { @class = "my-class" })</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Financials", "BudgetVSActualChart", "Financial")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "AdminView", "PMODashboard")</li>
            </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="navbar-text">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help will be appreciable
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the class dropdown to the item on which dropdown will appear and class dropdown-menu in the un ordered list tag  and it resolved my issue.

```
 <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("DashBoard", "ExecutiveDashboard", "Charts")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Engagement Metrics", "EngagementMatrix", "Charts")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Quality Metrics", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        @Html.ActionLink("People Aspects", "Contact", "Home")

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-inverse">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Certifications", "Index", "Certification")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Trainings", "Index", "Training")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Financials", "BudgetVSActualChart", "Financial")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "AdminView", "PMODashboard")</li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading in bootstrap anyway, you should use the bootstrap grid system. Add for example class="col-lg-3" to your div you want to rescrict in width. You can find more information about the grid system on [Bootstrap grid page](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/). This is always a nice way to make your page responsive!

Comment: I want to resyrict the width of sub menus when i hover on "People aspect " the dropdown which comes take the whole window i want it to restricted to the size of "People aspect " tab. I tried to assign  "col-lg-3" to each of the menu items in hope that it will restrict the size of submenu too but it was resulting very weird outcome

Comment: Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: I am trying to put the Sub menu under the link 4 just below it

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I found the problem you are having:
The problem is that .nav-collapse has a with of auto.

There are 2 ways you could fix this.

1. Overwrite the .collapse in your css file like:

```css
  .navbar-collapse {
      width:250px;
      box-shadow: none;
      border-top: 0px;
  }
```

2. You find your bootstrap.css file and look for the following 2 rules:

```css
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-collapse {
```

Here you remove the line that says width:auto;

I would advise you to use example 1.

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15970/)

Let me know if it works for you!
Cheers

Comment: It didn't resolve my issue .It was aligning all my navbar items vertically. I found the solution myself which i will post in answer. Thanx for your help anyway sir.